# can <main> element be nested inside a div or must be a direct descendant of body?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I am reading the docs but I still don't understand if the `<main>` element can be nested inside some other element e.g.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <main>...</main>
    </div>
</div>
```

or it must be a direct descendant of the body e.g.

```
<body>
    <main>...</main>
</body>
```

All the examples I've seen were showing the main as direct descendant of body...

So I am a bit confused: is it correct to put main inside some other element than body? (of course using it just one time)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#the-main-element)

> 4.4.13. The main element
>
> Categories:
>
> - Flow content.
> - Palpable content.
>
> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>
> Where [flow content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#flow-content) is expected, but with no `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<footer>`, `<header>` or `<nav>` element ancestors.

As the `<body>` and `<div>` elements may contain flow content, you are safe to nest them.

Comment: From the same site referred above:
> A **hierarchically correct `main` element** is one whose ancestor elements are limited to `html`, `body`, `div`, `form` without an [accessible name](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#dfn-accessible-name), and [autonomous custom elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#autonomous-custom-element). Each `main` element must be a [hierarchically correct `main` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#hierarchically-correct-main-element)